# T-SQL / SQL Server : multi table join query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Find the below attachment:

[image]

Currently I am trying to learn how to perform a multi-table join where one of the tables do not have a direct relationship (Standard PK-FK relationship) with the original table. Further, the desired output should be filtered out based on a few `WHERE` conditions.

I was assuming that if I joined `DealsFurtherInfo` table I should be able to bridge the relationship between the `Deals` and `Location Points` tables (since they do not share the `DealsUID` factor).

Here are the tables (originally from the image link)

Table: Deals

```
DealUID
CounterPartyUID
DealTypeUID
TradeDate
InactiveFlag
```

Table: CParties

```
CounterPartyUID
CounterPartyName
```

Table: DealsFurtherInfo

```
DealUID
LocationPointUID
```

Table: LocationPoints

```
LocationPointUID
LocationName
```

Desired output

```
DealUID   CounterPartyName   LocationName
```

Below is my code - If anyone could explain what am I doing incorrectly and walk me through SQL logic step by step, it would be highly appreciated.

```
SELECT 
    tblD.DealUID, 
    tblCP.CounterpartyName,
    tblPP.PointCode AS Location
FROM 
    Deals tblD
JOIN 
    CounterParties tblCP ON tblD.CpartyUID = tblCP.CpartyUID
JOIN 
    DealsFurtherInfo tblDPL ON tblD.DealUID = tblDPL.DealUID
JOIN 
    LocationPoints tblPP ON tblDPL.PointUID = tblPP.PointUID
WHERE 
    tblD.DealTypeUID = 20110 
    AND tblD.InactiveFlag = 'N' 
    AND tblD.TradeDate > '2019-01-01'
```

Comment: This looks okay. What is not working for you?

Comment: Don't put things like prefixes on your aliases. `D` is more than a good enough alias for an object called `Deals`.

Comment: Whats the relations between tables look like are they all 1:1 or some of them are 1:n. You just mentioned query is not working which should work for 1:1, and will give you possible duplicated results if 1:n. Can you also provide sample data and desired result.

Comment: tblPP.PointCode and tblPP.PointUID and tblDPL.PointUID don't exist in published table definitions. Typo in table definitions or typo in code?